# TensorFlow concat a variable-sized placeholder with a vector

Tags: concatenation, tensorflow

Let's say I have a placeholder

`ph_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, [None, 1])`

and a vector

`h = tf.zeros([1,2], dtype=tf.int32)`

In this example `h` is filled with zeros for simplicity but in the actual case it will be changed by other variables and will have different values.

I want to efficiently do a `concat` on `ph_input` and `h` on dimension `1` and get a new tensor with shape `[None, 1+2]`. Unfortunately `concat` needs all input tensors to have the same shape except the `concat_dim`, which my example does not meet.

I was considering expand `h` to the same shape as the data that feed to `ph_input` but am not exactly sure how to do that with the placeholder itself. If I get the shape from the input data directly then I guess it is not necessary to use the placeholder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most general solution is to use the [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) op to get the run-time size of the placeholder, and the [`tf.tile()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#tile) op to expand `h` to the appropriate size:

```
ph_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, 1])
h = tf.zeros([1, 2], dtype=tf.int32)  # ...or some other tensor of shape [1, 2]

# Get the number of rows in the fed value at run-time.
ph_num_rows = tf.shape(ph_input)[0]

# Makes a `ph_num_rows x 2` matrix, by tiling `h` along the row dimension.
h_tiled = tf.tile(h, tf.pack([ph_num_rows, 1]))

result = tf.concat(1, [ph_input, h_tiled])
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me with tf  10 and 11.

Comment: pack has been renamed to stack !